# NLP sentence summarization techniques with python

Tags: python, algorithm, nlp

I am trying to make a python script that takes a sentence and summarize it in 5-7 words with keywords and details.

So far, I have used the nltk library to first remove any symbols and numbers, then remove all word types except nouns and verbs. I also included a function to remove all stopwords(words without value like, 'the', 'it).

The code I have is extremely basic and the output isn't grammatically correct or understandable. My main objective is to take a sentence like:

"Drug stability refers to the ability of a pharmaceutical product to retain its quality, safety, and efficacy over time"

...and turn it into:

"Drug stability is ability to retain quality, safety, and efficacy"

But when i run the code I get "Drug stability refers ability pharmaceutical product retain quality, safety, efficacy time" which isn't bad but I want to make the system able to produce more grammatically correct while still retaining major keywords. I am aware of libraries like gensin or nltk summarize but these libraries only take the important sentences of a paragraph through word frequency but this doesn't simplify single sentences. are there any other methods for sentence summarization?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
def shortenSentence(sentence):
    #sentence = "%^Regulatory scientists must take measures to guarantee that the drug remains consistent and safe from the moment of production through packaging, storage, and shipping.907"
    clean_sentence = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z\s]', '', sentence)  # Added 0-9 and period (.)
    #print(clean_sentence)


    def remove_adj_adv(sentence):
        words = word_tokenize(sentence)
        pos_tags = pos_tag(words)
        shortened = [word for word, tag in pos_tags if tag in ['NN', 'NNS', 'VB', 'VBD', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBP', 'VBZ']]
        return ' '.join(shortened)
    shortened = remove_adj_adv(clean_sentence)
    #print(shortened)



    words = word_tokenize(shortened)
    # Get the list of English stopwords
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    # Remove stopwords from the list of words
    filtered_words = [word for word in words if word.lower() not in stop_words]
    # Join the filtered words back into a sentence
    filtered_sentence = ' '.join(filtered_words)
    #print(filtered_sentence)
    return(filtered_sentence)
```

Comment: Have you tried a large language model?

Comment: You should try working with a neural abstractive summarization system, as the task you are trying to solve is inherently abstractive sentence summarization. There are a bunch of them publicly available such as `bart-large`. I suggest, though, taking a look at `bart-large-cnn` or `bart-large-xsum` checkpoints that have already been trained on news corpora for abstractive summarization purpose. To work with these models, you may use Huggingface libary, which also has the checkpoints hosted in its model hub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you had a larger sentence?

While your approach works summarizing longer sentences may pose additional issues.

I would recommend adding two extra functions to your algorithm.

First, to identify important words using a representation schema such as TFIDF.

Second, set a threshold of min 10 to max 20 words to be included in the summary.

Since you are pre-processing the input text to remove unwanted words (stopwords, adjectives, etc.), reconstructing the sentence to be syntactically or grammatically correct, is a different problem, which may require using generative LLMs.

Thus, you should shift your focus from summarization to text generation based on keywords.